# Calculate inner divs width/height in mm (relative to outer div with known width/height in mm.)

Tags: javascript, math, dimensions

1. I have an outer div with a assigned width/height in mm. (mm is just assigned values, not used for rendering).
2. Inside it i have another div with a real width/height in px.
3. The two divs can have different ratios.

What i want to do is to calculate the inner divs width/height in mm. with JavaScript and also take scale into consideration.

**Example 1:** the outer divs assigned width/height is 30x30mm, scale is 0.8 and inner divs width/height in px is 600x600px, the result should then be 24x24mm.

**Example 2:** the outer divs assigned width/height is 60x30mm, scale is 1.0 and inner divs width/height in px is 300x600px, the result should then be 15x30mm.

The outer divs width/height in mm is considered max sizes.

Guess it's easy, but the fact that the divs/surfaces can have different ratios made it to complicated for me.

```
var calcDimensions = function(scale) {

   var surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight, contentWidth, contentHeight, contentRatio, surfaceRatio;

   // Output variable holding the result
   var dimensions = { width: 0, height: 0 };


   surfaceWidth = 30; // outer divs assigned width in mm
   surfaceHeight = 14; // outer divs assigned height in mm
   contentWidth = 600; // inner divs real width in px
   contentHeight = 196; // inner divs real height in px

   scale = 0.8; // Can have a value between 0.1 - 1.0

   contentRatio = contentWidth > contentHeight ? contentHeight / contentWidth : contentWidth / contentHeight; // Assuming this is needed in the calculation.
   surfaceRatio = surfaceWidth > surfaceHeight ? surfaceHeight / surfaceWidth : surfaceWidth / surfaceHeight; // Assuming this is needed in the calculation.

  // Calculate stuff here and return calculated dimensions

  return dimensions;
```

}

Comment: The point that I can't understand is why you use milimeters in a screen. Units like `mm`, `pt`, `pc`, `cm`, etc, are for printing systems, not for screens. If you use this measures in screens you will get serious and ambiguous problems (different sizes depending on the screen you use)

Comment: _“The two divs can have different ratios”_ – I don’t see how that should matter. And besides, I don’t see you making even an _attempt_ at calculating any dimensions in your code. So _what_ is it that you actually want to calculate here? You should come up with the proper formula first, before you even start coding it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude

Maybe i explained myself poorly, english is not my first language.

First off, mm on the div is just an tagged/assigned value, it has nothing to do with screen rendering, it's only there to calculate the width x height in mm for the inner div and will only be displayed as information (Eg. The inner div has a real size of 30x14 mm). This information will later be used for print.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It was rather the formula i was after, consider the function as a container and fill in the blanks below the "// Calculate stuff here".

I did actually somewhat solve it by using a bunch of if statements, but it has to be a more elegant way of calculating this

Example:

1. The outer div has an assigned width/height of 30x30mm
2. The inner div is 400x200px (double the width).
3. scale = 0.5

The result of the formula should be:
width = 15, height = 7.5

And also, the ratio of both the outer and inner div should be necessary for the formula (if i am not mistaking).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do the folowing:

Add a div in your view with width = 100mm

```
<div style="width:100mm;height:0" id="measure">
```

Maybe you have to set z-index or bg-color to make the div invisible.
Now you can calculate the count of pixels per mm on the device like this:

```
let pxPerMm = document.getElementById('measure').offsetWidth / 100;
```